# How to fix this mirror frame that is coming apart?

Tags: joinery, glue, wood-repair

I have an old dressing table, and the mirror frame is coming apart.

How best to repair it?
I am thinking carpenter glue, but I'm not sure.

[image: mirror frame]

Comment: Search for "frame" and "picture frame" to see previous Q&A that basically covers this.

Answer (score 3):

In general just getting some PVA glue in there and clamping the mitre closed (IF you can even do this with sufficient force) won't do enough, for a couple of reasons.

Regardless of the adhesive you want to use for the job when repairing a joint you really want to remove any previous glue residue so that as much as possible the new glue is bonding wood to wood, not trying to bond old glue to old glue. We can't really see what's going on in there from the photo but it appears not to be a plain, unreinforced mitre and as a result cleaning the mating surfaces will be difficult at best, even with some of the specialist tools used for such jobs<sup>1</sup>.

If one or more of the other corner joints is not rock solid ideally the frame needs to be taken apart (carefully!) and possibly all four corners re-glued, for a strong and long-lasting repair.

**If you're going ahead anyway**
If you must attempt to repair this as-is the number one priority is to do all you can to clean every surface that will be bonded together *without damaging them, or adjacent surfaces*. You can see how much easier this would be with the joint fully apart so you're not forced to work in such tight quarters.

But, check first if you can even clamp the mitre closed<sup>2</sup>.

Occasionally when a corner comes apart something will prevent the mitre from closing back tightly together as it should<sup>3</sup>, which again points to it being desirable to take the frame apart.

---

<sup>1</sup> Pros do this with some combination of carbide/steel scrapers, dental tools and sharp chisels. Some use of a heat gun or solvents may also be employed, depending on the previous glue used.

<sup>2</sup> Which needs to be done with the mirror off the dressing table.

<sup>3</sup> Glue from an old repair, splintered wood or a damaged/misplaced reinforcement such as a tenon or dowel.

Comment: It's the answer I was too lazy to provide.

Answer (score 3):

If this were mine, I would first clean the joint the best that I could. Chisel & mallet (gently!) or a paring chisel would do it. Go slow - doing more damage here isn't the idea. You want to make sure two things are accomplished:

1. You want that joint to close and stay closed (with clamps is fine). Make sure that anything that's in the way comes out.
2. You want to make sure that the mating surfaces are as clean as possible.

Save whatever you take out of the joint.

I'd use hide glue to repair the joint. It works great for things like this - especially if there's any chance you're going to need to repair it again. PVA (yellow glue) tends to get brittle and is often stronger than the wood that it's holding. That means if there's enough stress, the glue won't flex - it will snap and you'll have another repair to do.

Once the joint is clean, get the hide glue in there and clamp the joint. You can clean up squeeze-out with warm water (another benefit of hide glue!).

Why did you save whatever you took out of the joint? If there's a gap when you close the joint, you can mix the dust (not chunks) with the glue to help hide the gaps.